# How to make a charachter and/or car move on button press

Tags: game-engine

i would like to know how to get a object to move when you press a key, such as getting a car to move when the up arrow is pressed. I am relatively new to blender, but i hope to get into the animation/ game engine side of things soon.

Comment: Here you go https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atsvXJcg7XI Remember that Blender Game Engine is not much use this days. I recommend you to study how to import your mesh to Unity or Unreal Engine instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your editor type to logic editor,and here is your logic bricks
[image]